# Leetcode runtime decrease by iterating from i = 0 vs i = 1

Tags: c++, algorithm

I was trying out Running Sum of Array 1D in LC and it was stated that this solution:

```cpp
class Solution
{
public:
    vector<int> runningSum(vector<int> & nums) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++)
        {
            if (i > 0) {
                nums[i] += nums[i - 1];    
            }          
        }
        return nums;
    }
};
```

is faster than 78.36% of the submissions while this solution is only faster than 32.09%, despite needing to iterate through 1 less iteration.

```
class Solution
{
public:
    vector<int> runningSum(vector<int> & nums) {
        for (int i = 1; i < nums.size(); i++)
        {
                nums[i] += nums[i - 1];    
        }
        return nums;
    }
};
```

I am stumped - Can somebody explain to me why this is the case?

Comment: I would read nothing into it. Their code to do a test run probably has more variance than the difference between the speeds. It likely runs on a VM that shares CPUs with other things that may or may not conflict with it.

Comment: Does that even generate different code? I would expect the compiler to optimize that to the same code.